# ES Module import issue (React, Jest): SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I have set up a React application with the unit test cases using Jest.

For test cases I have 2 files, `.babelrc` and `setupTests.js`.

`.babelrc`:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

`setupTests.js`:

```js
// Jest configuration file
const Enzyme = require('enzyme');
const Adapter = require('enzyme-adapter-react-16');
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

The test cases are working fine until the time I'm using node_modules which are of type CommonJS.
Recently, I've installed `@fluentui/react-charting` which is an ES module. From then, I'm facing this import issue saying

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
```

I have tried a few ways to fix like

1. Updating type to module in `package.json`
2. renaming `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js`
3. adding `transform` and `transformIgnorePatterns` in `package.json`

But none of the above fixed the issue. Is there any workaround for the same?